# UWP - Save attributes of a xaml page (Slider/Combobox)

Tags: xaml, user-interface, uwp, c++-cx

I've got the following problem: In my main xaml page I've got a button which navigates to an other page which is called settings and which also includes settings for the app. I jump to the page with the following method:

`this->Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(Settings::typeid));`

As you can understand I want the UI-Elements (Comboboxes/Sliders) to save theier attributes for the next time. Not even for the next launch of the app, just for the next jump on the settings page. If I go back from settings to main page and back to settings again, the values of the comboboxes and slider are reseted. I need them to be saved for my program's logic.

In my c++-desktop app I'm using registry entrys in order to save it, but this is not quite possible in uwp and it's not the easiest solution. In Java I would use a global static variable which saves the values and which is bind to UI-elements. How can I implement this in UWP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [Page.NavigationCacheMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode). With that property you are able to store the state of the page in the cache of the application.
You can either use it in the xaml-tag of the page, or set in the constructor in the code-behind of the page. You can find the possible values of the properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode).

Example-XAML:

```
 <Page
    x:Class="Foo.Namespace.SettingsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Foo.Namespace"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    NavigationCacheMode="Enabled">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Example CS:

```
 public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
    {
        public SettingsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        }
    }
```